# function not called by nodejs ws-express on connection handler

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I've implemented a websockets api on top of a swagger-express node server.
For websockets I'm using [express-ws](https://github.com/HenningM/express-ws) which utilises the excellent [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) library.
However I have come across a problem where the function setInterval is not being called when a websocket client connects.
Confusingly though in the `ws.on('connection'`  function the `console.log('websocket connected');` does execute while the `setInterval` function does not. 
Can someone please point out what is wrong with my code?

```
'use strict';
var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var app = require('express')();
module.exports = app; // for testing
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

var IndexWS = require('./api/controllers/indexWS');

var config = {
    appRoot: __dirname // required config
};


app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {

    ws.on('connection', function(conn) {
        console.log('websocket connected');
        setInterval(function timeout() {
            console.log('conn');
        }, 500);

    });

    ws.on('close', function() {
        console.log('The connection was closed!');
    });

    ws.on('error', function() {
        console.log('websocket error!');
    });

    ws.on('message', function(msg) {
        setTimeout(function timeout() {
            ws.send("500 delay");
        }, 500);

    });
    console.log('websocket connected');
});

SwaggerExpress.create(config, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    // install middleware
    swaggerExpress.register(app);

    var port = process.env.PORT || 3030;
    app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0');

    if (swaggerExpress.runner.swagger.paths['/hello']) {
        console.log('server running on port ' + port );
    }
});
```

Comment: `console.log('conn'); does execute while the setInterval function does not` iconsole.log('conn'); is inside setInterval so this statement doesnt make sense.

Comment: @Ankur yes that was a mistake, I've now corrected it

Comment: Do you really want to use `setInterval` with 500ms? I mean it will run the function every 500ms forever. It seems you should be using setTimeout

Comment: Yes, as my plan is to put a pingpong heartbeat in there. The 500ms is just used during development, I'll put it to a more sensible delay